# Error pop up the app cannot be installed because its integrity iphone Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am tring to implement Azure push notification for my app.

setting provisioning and creating certificate all done.

and what currently i did in my code level is.

**App Delegate**

```
private void RegisterForRemoteNotifications()
        {
            LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications call : RegisterForRemoteNotifications");
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications inside version 10 or more");
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                                      (granted, error) =>
                                                                      {
                                                                          LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications {granted}");
                                                                          if (granted)
                                                                          {
                                                                              LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications calling : RegisterForRemoteNotifications");
                                                                              InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                                                                              LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications end : RegisterForRemoteNotifications");
                                                                          }
                                                                      });
            }
            else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications inside version 8 or more");
                var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                        new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            else
            {
                LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info($"Push Notifications inside version 10 or less");
                UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
            }
            
        }
```

When i set Push notification enable in Entitlement.plist

I ma getting a pop up

[image]

any help to fix this really appriciate.

Comment: I find you have install two EzyhaulCarrier in you device, how did you install this app? In your device, is there already an app installed with the same bundle identifier?

Comment: no actully if i delete also i get the same result.

what u see is not this it is different

Comment: @ChanduRanwala Hi, whether you use Visual Studio to install the app?

Comment: Basically I am uploading the .ipa to app center and download from there and install it in to my device. Then i see this error.

Comment: @ChanduRanwala Okey, do you have a check with the published certificate whether has expired first?

Comment: yes i have checked everything is fine, this is hapenning if i enable pushnotification on entitlement.plist.